# How to write test cases for buttons in another fragment in android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, user-interface

I have multiple fragments in my main activity, and I'm using bottom navigation too.
 I'm learning to write test cases with expresso for UI testing. I can test the buttons that are displayed on the opening fragment but the `OnView()` method only looks for views displayed currently in the view. How can I test the buttons in other fragments or activities ?
 Do I have to navigate there first by using `performclick()` or do i have to load them through the `onData()` method ? Can anyone help me ? I've attached some pictures below to help you understand.

Opening Fragment:

[image: openinig Fragment]

Second Fragment aka Devices fragment from the navbar:

[image: second Fragment]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: When doing UI testing with expresso, There is an option to record tests with expresso. You simply run the app and perform the actions and it generates the code accordingly and you can even put up assertions wherever you want. So if anyone was stuck on this . You should do it this way.